# Remove a PHP script from URL on Google

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I made a mistake *(I don't know how)* on my `.htaccess` and a part of my artilcle's links on Google have changed from:

```
mysite/articles/isfahan_articlesXXX.html
```

To:

```
mysite/maghalat.php/isfahan_articlesXXX.html?id=XXX
```

Where XXX is article's ID.
My current `.htaccess` part that contains articles is:

```
RewriteRule ^articles/isfahan_articles([0-9]+).html$ maghalat.php?id=$1
Redirect 301 ^maghalat.php/isfahan_articles([0-9]+).html?id=([0-9]+)$ mysite/articles/isfahan_articles$1.html
```

However it still will not redirect:

```
mysite/mghalat.php/isfahan_articlesXXX.html?id=XXX
```

To:

```
mysite/articles/isfahan_articlesXXX.html
```

I would also like to remove this link from Google:

```
mysite/articles/isfahan_articlesXXX.html
```

Comment: The best advice on such situation: yes, you can mess around with redirects if you want (although it is not trivial task considering situation as you may easily create infinite redirect), but instead just use `<link rel="canonical" href="PROPER_URL" />` and within a month or two (or even faster) Google will forget your wrong URLs in favour of correct one (as long as you will not publish wrong URLs on your site again). Just google for "link rel canonical" for exact instructions.

Comment: Regarding your redirect attempts: 1) `Redirect` & `RedirectMatch` directives do not match query strings. You current rule will NEVER match; 2) You are using regex in `Redirect` directive -- should be `RedirectMatch` -- read the docs; 3) Even then -- URL is wrong as it should start with leading slash; 4) The only way to match query string is to use RewriteRule in conjunction with RewriteCond; 5) You still can easily create redirect loop -- the rewrite rule has to be quite sophisticated to handle this. Considering all of the above -- go **rel=canonical** route.

Comment: What can I do please say me a practical way , by example please

Answer (score 1):

When you redirect using a 301 (moved permanently) status code, it will disappear from Google eventually.

Comment: do you mean my code: Redirect 301 ^maghalat.php/isfahan_articles([0-9]+).html?id=([0-9]+)$ mysite/articles/isfahan_articles$1.html is correct?! but when I try to open it it wont redirect to mysite/articles/isfahan_articlesXXX.html that show its a wrong rule , isn't it?

Comment: Ah, I see.. So the problem is, you do want the rewrite *to* mghalat (under water), but it shouldn't appear in Google.. The problem now, is that you can't both redirect the .php requests (from Google) to the .html file, and still push the .html requests to the .php file. You'll need to rename the .php file if you want to keep using that internally. If this is what you mean, let me know and I'll post some htaccess rules that should work for you.

Comment: Yes I want to replace maghalat.php to articles and remove id=XXX in : mysite/maghalat.php/isfahan_articlesXXX.html?id=XXX from Google

Comment: But do you still use maghalat for processing?

Comment: No maghalat.php is my php script that show article's body , I have 2 SEO friendly links on my .htaccess : one of them is for my old articles with following link : mysite/articles/isfahan_articlesXXX.html that currently have changed into Search Engines to mysite/maghalat.php/isfahan_articlesXXX.html?id=XXX , I wont to have this link on Search Engines it shows my PHP script and dropped my ranking ,I want to have my old link instead for my old articles : mysite/articles/isfahan_articlesXXX.html simply

Comment: Im waiting for your answer Rijk

Comment: Here's a good mod_rewrite tutorial: http://www.sitepoint.com/guide-url-rewriting/
Unfortunately, I don't have the time to write the rules myself. You might also find you have to rename the maghalat.php file.

Answer (score 1):

To remove pages from Google's index you need to create a google account and use [Google Webmaster Tools](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/). Add your website and Follow the instruction to validate that you are the owner of the site. There is an option to remove urls.

The pages you want to remove must meet [some criteria](https://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=59819&hl=en): They need be access restricted or return a 404 or 410 error code.

When the old urls are of your articles are blocked or removed, it's just a matter of time until the new ones will appear again in the google index.

Comment: I wont to remove it I want to change it to my old style : mysite/articles/isfahan_articlesXXX.html , actually I want replace "maghalat.php" to "articles" in my current link: mysite/maghalat.php/isfahan_articlesXXX.html?id=XXX and remove ?id=XXX

Answer (score 0):

You should check your links, its seems that this pages are created because of an error somewhere. But I'm just guessing.

You also can add a pattern in your robots.txt that disallow robot to crawl your pages.

Regards,